# I'm trying to set up 2FA for a Gnosis Safe using a Yubikey

Tags: gnosis-safe

"I'm trying to set up 2FA for a Gnosis Safe using a Yubikey (or other) for added security. I have experience with smart contract development and have followed the official documentation for integrating the Yubikey and Gnosis Safe, but I'm still encountering issues. Can anyone share their experience in setting up 2FA for a Gnosis Safe and provide any troubleshooting tips or resources that have been helpful for them? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated."